# coding a pictionary game with flutter

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

Hi everyone this is my first time codeing a game with flutter and I have a probleme creating a room using socket.io  I emit the roomName but I can't seem to get it on the server side
however I get the message that the io is connected How can I solve this probleme

the result is connected io! but i can't get the room name I enter after clicking on the button [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dE8b.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.